# Adding the text from a prompt box to a DataBase

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I make a simple web chat, and I use a prompt box triggered in `<body onload>` to get the user's nickname, the script is that:

```
function Login()
{
var x=prompt("Please enter your name","");
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// Използваните браузъри
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// Кой ли ползва тези версии..
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","login.php?u="+x,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Then, If the user has entered something I want to add this in a DataBase, or if nothing is entered I just want to assign "anonymos" as a nickname.For this purpose I use the following PHP script:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $u=$_GET["u"];
    $db_connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '******');
    if(!$db_connect)
        {
         die('Не може да се осъществи връзка с базата данни' . mysql_error());
        }
mysql_select_db("chat", $db_connect);
   if(is_null($u)==1)
            {
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name)  VALUES ('$u')";
mysql_query($sql);
$_SESSION['UserName']=$u;
             }
else
             {
                $_SESSION['UserName']='Anonymos';
             }
mysql_close($db_connect);

?>
```

But the code make problems, when nothing is entered sometimes I still get data in the DB where in the name filled I get null, for value, sometimes, this doesn't happen, and sometimes even If I enter some text it won't procceed it to the DB.I'm in lost here, cause when I do the check `If(is_null($u)` sometimes it works when I set it to 0, and sometimes it works when I set it to 1.The Table structure is very simple just id and name field, but I'm wondering if there could be a problem too?Thanks.Leron

I'm no sure, but maybe I figure out what the real cause of problem is - now I get the null record only when I press ESC key instead some of the prompt box buttons.I still don't know how to solve this, but because the has been pretty unstable I'm still looking for suggestions.

Comment: It seems that when ESC is pressed the variabale get default value of "null", so for now by simply checking $u!='null" I avoid the records with null as name value.I'll do some more testing and if it works and it's stable I'll consider it solved.Still glad to hear some opinions or explanations about what's happening exactly.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of is_null($u);

```
if (!empty($_GET["u"]))
```

and

```
$u= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["u"]);
```

this way if its empty it won't run

and if it runs it will be properly escaped to prevent sql injection

UPDATE:

Here is how your code can work

```
if(!empty($u)){
    // ... obviously you will need more validation then just not empty
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name)  VALUES ('%s')";
    $sql = sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($u));
    mysql_query($sql);
    $_SESSION['UserName']=$u;
}
else {
    $_SESSION['UserName']='Anonymos';
}
```

Comment: the value of $u will not be null, it will be an empty string if the user leave it blank, so it is a good idea to have the !empty function

Comment: I changed it with (!empty($u)) but still If no text is entered I get a DB record with null as a value of the name field

Comment: Hmm I think I figure out what the real problem is, now I get the null record when i press esc instead of clicking on the box buttons, how can I avoid this?

Comment: see my update, i dont think the problem is on the client side

Comment: When I use if(!empty($u)) I get null record only when ESC key is pressed, now when I try your script I get null record when I press ESC and when I click on the Cancel button in the prompt box.That's the change.

Comment: so what is the purpose of pressing escape? why do you press ESC

Comment: Well, I'm just learning, big part of this is just ot get used to use AJAX, JavaScript, DOM and so on.I just tried different cases, but most important in a real web application you cant just rely on the fact that the user won't press esccape, so now I'm thinking that maybe I should implement some logic where if ESC is pressed I still attach some value...dunno, it's my first time writing such thing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about php, but it seems to me that you need to check the 'u' parameter against the empty string:

instead of :

```
  if(is_null($u)==1)
```

use

```
 if(!is_null($u) && !empty($u))
```